# Charge a 3DS without a DS charger

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

I misplaced my 3DS charger. My 3DS is out of battery but for some reason it's urgent that I play it.

I'm going to get the charger back eventually but for now is there a way to charge a 3DS using something other than a DS charger?

Comment: Those are your choices.  Go back and get it, or go buy a new one.

Comment: There was actually a question buried in this post- I've dug it up. And one with an answer at that.

Comment: There is most likely another way to charge it, but that will probably require some advanced electrical knowledge and experience to pull off without damaging the system.

Comment: Why was this question downvoted? I did not witness its orginial creation (which by how @Studoku stated how he posted the comment on finding the question in the post, that it was more than likely a mess), but it seems like a valid question now.

Comment: @Shadowz Check the edit history. The original post was a complete mess with no effort put into spelling, grammar or punctuation. It got downvoted a bit in the 2 hours before I fixed it.

Comment: You can cut a USB 2.0, and plug the red wire into the the left inner port and white into the right inner port. USB should be putting out 500 ma 5v max. 3ds xl takes 4.6 v ~850 ma so you should be good. Left and right perspective assumes you are facing the charging port. I attached the USB wires to some cheap breadboard wires that have solid pins which makes it really easy to plug in. I have pics which I will post as soon as I figure out how. For some reason I can't submit this as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

According to Nintendo, [you can also charge your Nintendo 3DS using the Power Supply for a Nintendo DSi or Nintendo DSi XL.](https://www.nintendo.co.uk/Support/Nintendo-3DS-XL-/Usage-/Getting-started-/Charging/Charging-241839.html)

If you know someone with either one of those version, you could borrow their charger.
You could use a [USB cable from a third party](http://www.dx.com/p/usb-charging-cable-for-nintendo-3ds-100cm-110857#.U_Sx89ZSHqY)

Answer (score -3):

No, you can't charge it with anything else.